# Unable to import andengine library

Tags: android, eclipse, andengine

I am trying to import andegine to my project. I downloaded it [here](https://github.com/nicolasgramlich/AndEngine). However i cant import it on my eclipse juno mobile edition. here is the image.

[image]

Anyone can help me? Thank you..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to add the jar files of the **andEngine** to your current project. Since it is a library project, just add the files in you *lib* folder in order to access the library.

Comment: But i dont know where to download the jar files of andengine

Comment: When you got the andengine extension from github, it should prompt you to add the project into current workspace? Did you check that option?

Comment: You can add the project to your workspace by File->import->Git->projects from Git->Local, and select your andengine repository. Follow [this link](http://www.andengine.org/forums/tutorials/getting-started-with-andengine-t4858-180.html) for further help.